no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist
I'm trying to pass a List of items from one Activity to another but I keep getting this error:

no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that PlaylistItem conforms
to List

List<PlaylistItem> playlists = new ArrayList<>();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyApp.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle;
bundle.putSerializable("playlists", (Serializable) playlists);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);


public class MyApp extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        List<PlaylistItem> playlistItems = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("playlists", PlaylistItem.class); 

    }
}


Would you consider to use Parcelable instead of Serializable?

getIntent().getSerializableExtra("playlists", PlaylistItem.class); -- this code returns a PlaylistItem, not a List<PlaylistItem>. Note that passing large data structures like this via Intent extras has been an anti-pattern for a decade or so. Please consider modern architecture: caching your playlists in a repository, and retrieving them (perhaps via passed identifiers) from the repository.

If it helps anyone in the future, you have to use getParcelableArrayListExtra not getSerializableExtra which requires your class to implement Parcelable instead of Serializable

Thanks for the update. Feel free to answer with your solution below rather than a comment

You have to use getParcelableArrayListExtra not getSerializableExtra which requires your class to implement Parcelable instead of Serializable.
